# Edit URL without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a URL without refreshing the page. My initial URL is

```
data:text/html,http://arget.com
```

I want change this to

```
http://arget.com
```

I want remove `data:text/html,` in the URL without refreshing the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: less descriptive, don't be shy in adding proper information!

Comment: Why can you not refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [The history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) allows you to modify *parts* of the URL displayed in the address bar, but it won't let you touch the origin (i.e. since the content came from the URL and not from arget.com's servers, there is no way to make the browser claim it came from arget.com's servers). That would make things very easy for phishing attackers.